# Can a print test be performed to determine nozzle and filament quality?

Tags: print-quality, filament, nozzle, quality, filament-quality

Given that, a printer is well-maintained and calibrated.

I'm searching for a particular nozzle accuracy and filament quality test:

- First, is there a specific print test that can be performed to test the quality of the nozzle alone, based on the visual results? Can that be reflected in a score of some kind, a metric reflecting the nozzle quality?
- Secondly, is there a specific print test to test the filament quality, **not strength properties**, solely based on the visual results? Can that be reflected in a filament quality score or metric?
- Lastly, are there "known good" standards that results could be compared with?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "quality"?

Comment: Perhaps nozzle (diameter) accuracy is a better term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Mostly a Relative measure

Assuming you have a well-known, well-printing nozzle and filament combination, then you can print a **benchmark** print, change one factor and then test with altered settings.

One of the most ubiquitous prints for a benchmark is [Benchy](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/18604/why-is-a-3d-benchy-considered-a-good-test-print-for-fdm-printers). Benchy isn't so much a calibration test, but has all aspects you need in a benchmark. Overhangs, rounded corners, sharp corners, small diameter parts and sharp corners followed by longer stretches: it's all in there! and with those one gets a decent idea of print quality for other parts.

Another typical benchmark test is a cube, which has the sharp corners and stretches.

Depending on which factors you switched, you get a resulting **relative** quality comparison between the two prints. But you won't get a *measurable* metric, unless you invent a score based on artifacts.

### Filament factors

Among the factors that would show up based on bad filament. The three most noticeable I can think of are:

- hissing, bubbling & gaps can indicate wet filament
- stretches of random underextrusion and motor skipping can indicate uneven filament diameter
- sudden stalling of the extruder and no extrusion indicates a bulge on the filament

### Nozzle factors

Nozzle problems generally are systemic and would show up on the whole print.

- clogs from bad machining result in systematic underextrusion or no extrusion at all
- too large a nozzle shows in a larger print
- too small a nozzle shows in bad wall-to-wall and inter-layer adhesion and extruder skipping